# noUISlider - How to destroy the noUiSlider without deleting the element?

Tags: nouislider

I have an  element in my HTML and it has some HTML inside it. I am converting that to noUISlider at the click of a button (Start Slider). There is another button to hide the slider (Hide Slider). I want to hide the slider but keep the  and also the HTML inside it. I am trying the slider.nouislider.destroy(); but it deletes the element completely.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thank you.

Suhas

Answer (score -1):

Okay, this is what I did and it worked for me. Hopefully, it could be helpful to someone or if there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

My HTML is

```
<div class="sliderContainer" id="slider">some HTML code</div>
```

And My JS code is

```
var sliderActive = false;

function createSlider() {
    if (!sliderActive) {
        sliderActive = true;
        noUiSlider.create(slider, {
            start: [360, 1080],
            connect: true,
            step: 15,
            behaviour: 'drag',
            tooltips: [
                {
                    to: function (value) {
                        return processValue(value);
                    },
                    from: function (value) {
                        return processValue(value);
                    }
                },
                {
                    to: function (value) {
                        return processValue(value);
                    },
                    from: function (value) {
                        return processValue(value);
                    }
                },
            ],
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                'max': 1440,
            }
        });
    }
}

function destroySlider() {
    sliderActive = false;
    $('.sliderContainer').attr('class', 'sliderContainer');
    $('.noUi-base').remove();
    delete slider.noUiSlider;
    slider = document.getElementById('slider');
}
```

Thank you.